# Pandas Merge Rows with same UserID

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that represents posts with information about the user that posted it and the tags associated with it.

```
          UserID      PostID  Tags   
0           1         1        A   
1           2         2        A    
2           1         3        A    
3           2         4        B   
4           3         5        B    
5           4         6        B    
6           5         7        A
```

I want to create a new dataframe with each row representing a user like this.

```
          UserID      Posts     Tags   
0           1         [1,3]     [A,A]   
1           2         [2,4]     [A,B]   
2           3         [5]       [B]    
3           4         [6]       [B]   
4           5         [7]       [A]
```

So that I can have a list of there posts and tags rather than having them each be individual.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use groupby.agg with `list`:

```
df.groupby('UserID', as_index=False)['PostID', 'Tags'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
Out: 
   UserID  PostID    Tags
0       1  [1, 3]  [A, A]
1       2  [2, 4]  [A, B]
2       3     [5]     [B]
3       4     [6]     [B]
4       5     [7]     [A]
```